# How to make a Blind Shipment label

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to remove the From address on the labels that are produced when a shipment is confirmed, AKA blind shipment label.  I found the SOShipmentEntry.ShipPackages() method which seems to attach the label file to the packages on the shipment.  Following that code back, I'm not seeing any jump off points to tell the respective carriers' API that the shipment is a "blind shipment" or blank out the return address on the label.

I've tried clearing out a couple of the addresses on the shipment request to the carrier API but, they always come back with a validation error.

Has anybody tried this and can maybe shed some light?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The carrier plugin is what retrieves/generates the label and then passes that back to the system.

If the carrier does have an API option to support hiding the address, you could write a customization to add support for it however that most likely would involve writing a new plugin.

I doubt most carriers have API options to hide the from address so your only other option would be to modify the label after it is returned from the carrier which would differ based on what format it was returned in.